# Find the precise condition on a,b,c, and d under which the linear combinations ax+by and cx+dy are perpendicular.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, vectors

"Let $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ be two perpendicular unit vectors.

(a) Find a formula for the magnitude of an arbitrary linear combination
$$a\mathbf{x} + b\mathbf{y}$$ of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

(b) Find the precise condition on $a, b, c$ and $d$ under which the linear combinations
$$a\mathbf{x} + b\mathbf{y} \text{ and } c\mathbf{x} + d \mathbf{y}$$are perpendicular.

A purely geometric proof will not receive full credit; try to use vectors! "

My progress so far: I have already solved a). Since the unit vectors are just $(1;0)$ and $(0;1)$, the magnitude of linear combination $a\mathbf x+b\mathbf y$ is just $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

For b),
I know that for $a\mathbf x+b\mathbf y$ and $c\mathbf x+d\mathbf y$ to be perpendicular their dot product is $0$.
So I have $(a\mathbf x+b\mathbf y) \cdot (c\mathbf x+d\mathbf y) =0$.

This expands to $a\mathbf x \cdot c\mathbf x + a\mathbf x \cdot d\mathbf y + b\mathbf y \cdot c\mathbf x + b\mathbf y \cdot c\mathbf y$
Then I simplified to $ac||\mathbf x||^2 + a\mathbf x \cdot d\mathbf y + b\mathbf y \cdot c\mathbf x + bd||\mathbf y||^2=0$

I'm stuck on how to simplify this further. Help / hints is appreciated , thank you!

Comment: Since $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ are unit vectors you know what their norm is. In addition, they are orthogonal to each other so you also know what their dot product is.

Comment: @Patricio Sorry, we haven't learned about norms yet.
But using the fact that perpendicular vectors are orthogonal, I get ac|x||^2 + bd|y||^2 =0

Comment: You use norms in your question! How can you claim not to have learned about them? $\|\mathbf x\|$ is the *norm* of $\mathbf x$. A *unit* vector is a vector of norm $1$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Isn't that the magnitude?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Wait nevermind, I got the solution. I got ac+bd=0 thank you

Comment: The $\|\ \ \|$operator that carries a vector to its magnitude is called a "norm". And "norm of $\mathbf x$" is how you will more commonly hear it called as you move forward in math. I guess I should have thought about you just not having heard that name before.